# Google analytics track event time

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am tracking custom events in my web app and I would like to track the time of the event. As value field is integer only I cannot track the time value there.

Example event

`ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');`

Now I would like to track when this event happened, so I tried below code but it does not work.

`ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign', new Date());`

I can track timing event separately but I would like to track it only once so I can generate the graphs based on time.

Answer (score 0):

When a hit is received by Google Analytics the time is tracked already.

As you have already stated [event value](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ev) must be a number you cant send date.

> Event Value
>   Specifies the event value. Values must be non-negative.
>   ev integer 
>   Example value: 55 
>   Example usage: ev=55

If memory serves it can be a decimal as well 1.34 *(undocumented feature kind of thing)*

I wonder if you could send [Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) though not sure how big a number you can actually send.

Still not sure you need to be doing this, since the data is already there.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I see time tracked with the hit?

Comment: add a secondary dimension of minute or hour to any report.   Use the api to extract hour minute and date along with your other event metadata.   There are a number of ways to see it.